# Quiero cojer elementos de una lista individualmente y sumarlos entre ellos que debo hacer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

mi codigo es este:

```
num=input('Pon 10 numeros')
print(list(num 0)+(num 1)+(num 2)+(num 3)+(num 4)+(num 5)+(num 6)+(num 7,)+(num 8)+(num 9))
```

Comment: Uri, bienvenido. Te invito a hacer el recorrido inicial en este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour. ¿Podrías dar más detalles sobre lo que quieres hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Con **input**, del mismo modo en que lo hiciste tu, capturo una **cadena** de caracteres númericos. No realicé ninguna validación para no complicar la respuesta.

> numeros=input("Ingrese 3 números (separados con comas): ")

Luego, luego uso **split(",")** para transformar la cadena en una lista que quedará en una nueva variable:

> lista_de_numeros = numeros.split(",")

A continuación realizo la suma de dos formas, la habitual, con un ciclo **for**, y después, del modo en que solicitas en el enunciado de tu pregunta.

```
numeros=input("Ingrese 3 números (separados con comas): ")
resultado_suma = 0
lista_de_numeros = numeros.split(",")

for cada_numero in lista_de_numeros:
    resultado_suma += int(cada_numero)

print("Sumado dentro de un ciclo:")
print(resultado_suma)

print("Sumado como en tu ejemplo:")
print(int(lista_de_numeros[0]) + int(lista_de_numeros[1]) + int(lista_de_numeros[2]))
```

Cabe destacar, que sumar del modo en que quieres, es mucho más engorroso a nivel de codificación, que hacerlo con ciclo; Yo reduje el ejemplo a **3** por lo mismo. Tendrías que escribir **n** veces **int(lista_de_numeros[1])** según el ejemplo, donde **n** es la cantidad de números ingresados.
En cambio, la solución que incluye el uso de un ciclo, es la misma, sin importar la cantidad de elementos de la lista.